# Microsoft Graph API Contacts Subscription - Not Receiving Notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

We are migrating over from Outlook API that is deprecated to Microsoft Graph API. We have a working flow where we are subscribed to a user's contacts changed/created/deleted events.

I created a subscription and got back a 201 response and the following:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
"id":"xxxxxxx",
"resource":"me/contactFolders/YYYYYYYYYYY/contacts",
"applicationId":"ZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
"changeType":"created,updated,deleted",
"clientState":null,
"notificationUrl":"https://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx",
"notificationQueryOptions":null,
"notificationContentType":"application/json",
"lifecycleNotificationUrl":null,
"expirationDateTime":"2022-05-21T17:05:09Z",
"creatorId":"444444444444",
"includeResourceData":null,
"latestSupportedTlsVersion":"v1_2",
"encryptionCertificate":null,
"encryptionCertificateId":null,
"notificationUrlAppId":null}
```

However, I've tried to subscribe to just "me/contacts" instead of a specific folder as well but no matter what I do, my notification URL does not receive any notifications.   I have subscriptions for email messages and that one works fine.  Is there something that is different with receiving notifications from the old Outlook API vs Microsoft Graph's subscription notification?

Comment: Could you please go through the following limitations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#contact-event-and-message and check if you are following the same?

Comment: Yes, I have all the permissions. I can call the API to get contacts, update, delete contacts.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Any other ideas?

Comment: @james I am also facing the same issue, did you able to find any solutions for receiving contacts  notification?

Comment: No, I have not, I have had to create a work around and poll user accounts using the delta link. Not exactly efficient and best long term solution but does the trick for now.

Comment: Hi @james, did the issue got resolved?

Comment: @Shweta yes, I magically started getting notifications without making any changes...